# @Angular routing not working - 404

Tags: angular

When I run angular router, I get the `404 status - page not found`

I've been trying to follow the @angular docs to get the routing for a test site setup.

- [Angular Routing Tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5)
- [Angular Router Guide](https://angular.io/guide/router)

It is partially working, because I setup a redirect in the `app-routing.module.ts` file, and it successfully redirects from `localhost:4200` to `localhost:4200/test`.

However, once at that path I get a 404 error. It should be displaying the component I routed to that path.

### Code

I have one component called anomalies

#### Project Structure

leaving out the files I believe to be non-relevant to this problem (I built the project with ng commands, so the rest should be as expected)

```
app/
  anomalies/
    anomalies.component.css
    anomalies.component.html
    anomalies.component.spec.ts
    anomalies.component.ts
  app-routing.module.ts
  app.module.ts
```

#### app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AnomaliesComponent } from './anomalies/anomalies.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'test',
    component: AnomaliesComponent
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'test',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})

export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

#### app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AnomaliesComponent } from './anomalies/anomalies.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AnomaliesComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

#### anomalies/anomalies.component.html

```
<p>
  anomalies works!

  well, not yet.
</p>
```

Comment: I couldn't understand what issue you are facing.. You said it successfully redirects. Even though it redirects, the html is not loading and it throws this error?

Comment: yep, that's correct

Comment: Dude, I literally copied and pasted your code and it worked.. Try to stop application and serve it again. Or it's a kinda issue that I've never seen before. https://github.com/garapa/studying/tree/master/testRouting

Comment: I've stopped and started it, but had the same issue... maybe you're right and this is a new issue. Going to keep trying for a bit longer

Comment: Can you put a piece of code into https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-grc3nx .

Comment: @Alter, there are few other things that are missing, please add them to your question: a) full http url from browser console that fails with 404; b) code of AppComponent (typescript and template); c) code of AnomaliesComponent (typescript). Even if the typescripts do not contain any meaningful code - it is component declarations that are needed in order to understand the problem.

Comment: Sure, all of them were left as default generated by angular-cli. The url was the one listed in my redirect

Comment: Are you trying to navigate *directly* to `localhost:4200/test` (eg is that the URL you put into the browser's address bar), or are you letting angular redirect you?

Comment: I was letting angular redirect me, but I'm having trouble typing it in. Do you know how to get around that?

Answer (score 2):

Defing two things in case its missed :

1. index.html should have a 
   `<base-href='/'>`
2. You should have router-outlet defined in app.component.html
   `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

Answer (score 0):

the `<router-outlet>` tag was required in app.component.html

## Code

#### app.component.html

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```